# Vaadin data model doesn' t update

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to develop my first application in vaadin. I saw a little of components, layout ..... and now i'm trying to learn how bind the UI component with the DataModel.

I have this class

```
public class Utente {

private String nome = "Mario";
private String cognome = "Rossi";


public Utente() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}

public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
}

}
```

and this CustomComponent

```
public class MyRegistration extends CustomComponent {

private FormLayout mainLayout;
private Button buttonSalva;
private Utente utente;
private BeanItem<Utente> beanItem;
private FieldGroup fieldGroup;

public MyRegistration() {
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
}

private FormLayout buildMainLayout() {

    utente = new Utente();
    beanItem = new BeanItem<Utente>(utente);
    fieldGroup = new FieldGroup(beanItem);
    mainLayout = new FormLayout();

    setWidth("100.0%");
    setHeight("100.0%");

    mainLayout.addComponent(fieldGroup.buildAndBind("Nome", "nome"));
    mainLayout.addComponent(fieldGroup.buildAndBind("Cognome", "cognome"));

    // buttonSalva
    buttonSalva = new Button();
    buttonSalva.setCaption("Salva");
    mainLayout.addComponent(buttonSalva);

    addListener();

    return mainLayout;
}

private void addListener(){

    buttonSalva.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println(fieldGroup.getItemDataSource());
        }
    });
}

}
```

my trouble is that if I press the button, i show always Mario Rossi also if i modify the content of the fields.

Where i wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to commit the changes by saying

```
fieldGroup.commit();
```

or set the field group in non-buffered mode:

```
fieldGroup.setBuffered(false);
```